# When to delete Push subscription from server

Tags: push-notification, web-push

Just started playing with push notifications and I managed to handle all the subscription process and I'm saving endpoints and keys on my db. My questions is, what strategy should I follow, if any, to delete old subcription details from the database?.
So, if someone allowed notifications and they revoke the permission how do I know who did it to remove the details from the database?. Because if the user unsubscribes I'll just get a null subscription from pushManager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Pushpad we use these two strategies:

- when a user revokes the permission the requests made using that endpoint will return `410 Gone` and you should delete the endpoint
- a developer can optionally trigger an unsubscribe with the Javascript SDK that will remove the endpoint from the server (this is useful for example to create a subscribe/unsubscribe button on the website)

Comment: That sounds like a great approach. Thanks.